# Can I resist damage from Fireball spell, if I have fire resistance trait?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance

Can I reduce fire damage from spells, if I have fire resistance? Or does it only help with non-magic damage?

If the latter is right, what does the Elemental Adept feat mean "Spells you cast ignore resistance to damage", if damage from spells is already magical?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot. I talked about D&D 5e.

Comment: No problem, but please put system/edition in tags, not in comments or (only) in the body of the question. I’ve done that for you here (and added some extra spaces because it looked like you intended them; you need two spaces in a row to start a new paragraph in this system).

Comment: No problem; there’s some decent explanations in the [Tour], so I recommend that if you haven’t yet, but we also expect newcomers to make some mistakes (for that matter, we expect old hats to make some mistakes some of the time, too, though hopefully less often).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fire resistance applies to any and all damage that’s called fire. This is described on page 197 of *Player’s Handbook*:

> If a creature or an object has resistance to a damage type, damage of that type is halved against it.

No ifs, ands, or buts here; damage of the indicated type is halved. So if your resistance says *fire*, and the spells says *fire*, the spell does half damage. Elemental Adept defeats that protection, however.

Later in that same section, *Player’s Handbook* even includes an example of fire resistance explicitly combined with nonmagical resistance:

> Multiple instances of resistance or vulnerability that affect the same damage type count as only one instance. For example, if a creature has resistance to fire damage as well as resistance to nonmagical damage, the damage of a nonmagical fire is reduced by half against that creature, not reduced by three-quarters.

This example would not make very much sense if fire resistance only worked for nonmagical fire, because then the fire resistance would be completely redundant.